# iOS 9.3 Beta 3 NSUserDefaults Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

So firstly, if I'm not allowed to mention beta/pre-release software then apologies. I was unaware and will be aware when you tell me off! Right

But otherwise, Im having an issue with iOS 9.3 Beta 3 where the **NSUserDefaults** values in my app are not always being remembered between app launches. It would appear that other app store apps are also having this issue as many of them Ive opened recently have said 'Oh this is your first launch' or something similar so I guess other developers like me have been using **NSUserDefaults** to check if the user has opened the app before.

Does anyone have a clue what might be causing this?

Is this a bug?

Comment: You need to post the code that it is not working

Comment: If you can reliably reproduce the problem then you should report the bug to Apple via the developer page; that's what Beta is for.

Comment: Theres no point posting code, to anyone who could understand the issue its fairly self explanatory and Im suggesting it affects apps code that I don't even have access to. Cheers Paulw11 I'll report it and see where that get me

Comment: I am seeing this behaviour currently on the release version of 9.3... Which is worrying, many of my App Store apps from other developers (including Hue and Whatsapp) are launching as though I've never used them before - very annoying Apple.

Comment: Same issue here, very annoying... I get nil values from random variables stored in userDefaults, walkthrough restart first, now it return nil for a value that has been previously stored... it seems only a read problem. Also Whatsapp asked me to insert my phone number 3 times...